# how to include standard header files when compiling a kernel module source?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel-module

I've downloaded, compiled and installed the latest kernel in my machine. Now, I'm trying to write a kernel module. When I try compiling it, I get errors of following similar sort - 
    fatal error: sys/syscall.h: No such file or directory
    fatal error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory
I've tried rewriting the makefile for this in the fashion of including the necessary directories from the source of my latest kernel, but still the problem is persistent.

Require your suggestions.

Comment: Show us the code. Also, you shouldn't be including standard header files in your module.

Comment: Have you read any kernel module tutorials? Modern kernels comes with an entire build environment for modules, you should use that. (In other words: Show us what you got before asking about the problem.) Does [this simple example](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x208.htm) work for you?

Comment: Can you show us the makefile please?

Comment: My Make file looks something like this - 
  [code]
  obj-m += file.o
  all:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
  clean:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
Well, in one of the Kernel Module tutorials, I was suggested to include these header files. I'm new in this arena, and hence used whatever was suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use libc headers in the kernel.

Moreover, you seem to include syscall.h. Syscalls are by nature userspace call. There is no need for syscalls inside the kernel.

The include for linux/module.h should work though. Could you give us the Makefile you are using ?

Comment: My Make file looks something like this - 

  obj-m += file.o
  all:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
  clean:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

Well, in one of the Kernel Module tutorials, I was suggested to include these header files. I'm new in this arena, and hence used whatever was suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Makefile` should look something like this.

```
hello.ko: hello.c
  make ARCH=um -C "/home/abhijit/play/kernel/linux-2.6" M=`pwd` modules

obj-m:= hello.o
objs:= hello.o
```

and you should have a `module_init` and `module_exit` defined in your source file.
Do you have these things?